# How to create and download csv file in cordova mobile app with button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, inappbrowser

I am doing a sample app using cordova, HTML and javascript. I am trying to download one sample csv file with dynamic data. The file is downloading in the desktop version. Once i create APK and install in the mobile,i'm unable to download the file.

What to do for this.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try following for Dynamically Creating CSV Files on the Client

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/04/03/Dynamically-Creating-CSV-Files-on-the-Client/